# Antiderivative of a piecewise continuous function

Tags: calculus

I have a silly conceptual confusion. Let's consider a piecewise continuous function: $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x\in(0,1),
\\  1 & \text{if } x\in[1,2),
\\ 3-x & \text{if } x\in [2,3).
\end{cases}
$$
By definition $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,3)$. Then, (please correct me if I'm wrong) its antiderivative is given by $$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
\tfrac12x^2+c_1  & \text{if } x\in(0,1),
\\ x+c_2  & \text{if } x\in[1,2),
\\ 3x-\tfrac12x^2+c_3  & \text{if } x\in[2,3),
\end{cases}
$$
where $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ **are not necessarily equal** (right?). So my question is, the antiderivative of a piecewise continuous function is not necessarily continuous, right? That would depend on the specific values of $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$, right? So for example $F(x)$ with $c_1=1$, $c_2=-20$, $c_3=0$ should be a not continuous antiderivative of $f(x)$, or should I choose $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ such that they make $F(x)$ continuous? If the answer is that I have to choose $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ so that $F(x)$ is continuous, what if $f(x)$ wasn't continuous in the first place, then can I choose them to be different? In that case, would $F(x)$ still be an antiderivative?

Comment: Antiderivative in this case may not be a well defined concept (unless you define it). But what you are probably interested is $F(x)=\int_0^x dt\, f(t)$. This function is continuous and differentiable in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want $F$ to be an antiderivative on $(0,3)$, then it has to be continuous (and actually differentiable) at $1$ and $2$. This means that once you choose $c_1$, you would be forced to choose a particular $c_2, c_3$ to make the functions values (and derivatives) match from the left and right at $x=1$ and $x=2$.

If you don't pick the $c_1, c_2, c_3$ consistently, you won't have $F'(1)=f(1)$ and $F'(2)=f(2)$, and $F$ won't be an antiderivative of $f$ on $(0,3)$. It will only be an antiderivative of $f$ on $(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup (2,3)$.

Comment: I see, it makes sense, thank you. Just one last question, if the last part of the function $f(x)$ for $x\in[2,3)$ was given so that $f(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=2$, then I would be allowed to choose $c_3$ independently, right? Since now I don't need $F'(x)$ to be continuous anymore(??)

Comment: You still need $F'(2)=f(2)$, which requires that $F$ is continuous (and in fact differentiable) at $x=2$. Whether or not $f$ is continuous/differentiable at a point doesn't change this.

Comment: But in that case, if $f(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=2$, we can say for sure that $F(x)$ won't be differentiable at that point, just continuous, right?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $2$, then it doesn't have an antiderivative on $(0,3)$. So you can define $F$ as stated in the problem, and, as you say, it won't be differentiable at $x=2$. But it also won't be an antiderivative of $f$ on $(0,3)$. It would be an antiderivative of $f$ on $(0,2)\cup (2,3)$. 

By contraposition, if we're assuming that $f$ actually has an antiderivative on $(0,3)$, it won't have jump discontinuities.

Answer (score -1):

No, the antiderivative should be continuous, so you should choose the $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that they are continuous.

In general, the antiderivative $F$ is only defined for functions that are everywhere continuous on their domain.

Should you wish to generalize this definition to functions that are not everywhere continuous, e.g. $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<0,\\1&x\geq0,\end{cases}$$ then it makes sense to require the fundamental theorem of calculus to hold, i.e. it should satisfy $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)$. This only holds if the antiderivative is continuous. In our example, it would be $$F(x)=\begin{cases}c&x<0,\\x+c&x\geq0.\end{cases}$$ Indeed, one can check that $F(x)$ satisfies $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)$ for all $a<b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (That is, all $x$ where $f$ is continuous)

Comment: "In general, the antiderivative $F$ is only defined for functions that are everywhere continuous." 

This is simply not true. $F$ is an antiderivative of $F$ if $F'=f$, regardless of whether $f$ is everywhere continuous.

Comment: "Should you wish to generalize this definition to functions that are not everywhere continuous, then it makes sense to require the fundamental theorem of calculus to hold." If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on an interval, then it is, by definition, differentiable on that interval and, *a fortiori*, it is continuous on that interval. "Requiring the fundamental theorem of calculus" to hold is unnecessary. It's also not possible to "require" the FTC to hold for general antiderivatives.

Comment: If you have a function like $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\mathrm{if}\ x<0\\1&\mathrm{if}\ x\geq0\end{cases}$, then this function is not continuous, but it does have a function $F$ for which the FTC holds, which is $F(x)=\begin{cases}c&\mathrm{if}\ x<0\\x+c&\mathrm{if}\ x\geq0\end{cases}$. This is _almost_ an antiderivative ($F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ for which $F'(x)$ is defined), and one can generalize the definition as such.

Comment: I edited my answer to clear up the confusion.